# Is this a real site?

Tags: discussion, bug

It has no questions and seems *awfully* specific.  It's surely on-topic for other sites in the network, but yet it seems to publicly exist.

http://cs50.stackexchange.com

Comment: @mhlester Almost certainly; I don't know why it didn't come up in my search. Probably a client-side thing—wouldn't be unprecedented.  Feel 100% free to close as dupe.

Comment: Is this just fantasy? Caught in a landslide, no escape from reality...

Comment: Points for quoting Queen.

Comment: Good question, was also wondering about this. I also noticed http://edx-cs169-1x.stackexchange.com/, which has questions. But it still seems really weird for a course to have a stackexchange website...

Comment: @MonKeePoo I'd take a look at the linked; it answers (and opens) a lot of questions.